# Content disposition

Tags: python

am using  xlwt module to create xls file with multiple sheets and i want to display Content disposition with the created file.

```
 wbk = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
 sheet = workbook.add_sheet('sheet1')
```

and then

```
 response.headers['Content-Type'] = \
    gluon.contenttype.contenttype('.xls')
response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=projects.xls'\
```

how can i make the content of wbk inside projects.xls?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the docs](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html#xlwt.Workbook-class), it seems that you could write out to a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html), and then print that out.

```
import StringIO
output = StringIO.StringIO()
wbk.save(output)
```

and then use `output.getvalue()`.

I have not tested this at all.

Comment: I suppose I should mention that, if using CPython, I'd probably use cStringIO.  Whether or not you need it depends on your situation, though.

Answer (score 2):

[dis]claimer: I'm the maintainer of xlwt.

`Workbook.save(destination)` ...

if `destination` is an object with a `write` method (e.g. obtained by [c]StringIO.StringIO()):

xlwt writes to this but doesn't close it. What you use this for and how you dispose of the object are up to you.

else:

xlwt assumes that `destination` is a string which is interpreted as a file path; xlwt attempts to open a file, write to it, and close it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`response.body`](https://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#response) attribute to write the excel file:

```
wbk.save(response.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

in Django you would simply :

```
response = HttpResponse(my_data, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=foo.xls'

wbk.save(response)
```